# Select from recursive call result in plsql

Tags: oracle, graph, plsql

**TL;DR**

In PL\SQL, I need to return a collection type on which I can do a SELECT, but I cannot select from a table of record : `PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements`.

**Long version**

I have a table representing nodes of a graph and a table representing it's oriented arcs :

```
node_table(
    node_id int,
    data 
)

arc_table(
    source_node_id int,
    destination_node_id int
)
```

In a package, I have a recursive algorithm representing a graph traversal. It returns all the possible nodes currently visited for a condition and a number of step. It presumes that we can start on any node. The pseudo-codes goes like this.

```
function getPossibleNodes(number_of_steps, condition):
returns node_collection_type
declare 
    previous_result  node_collection_type
    result           node_collection_type
begin
    if number_of_step = 0:
        select node_id 
        bulk collect into result 
        from node_table;
    else
        previous_result = getPossibleNodes(number_of_steps - 1, condition);
        select destination_node_id 
        bulk collect into result
        from node_table join arc_table on 
            node_id = source_node_id
        where *condition*
    end id;
    return result;
end;
```

The problematic is the format of the returned data. I wanted to return a table of record, declared in this way :

```
TYPE node_search IS RECORD (
    ID INT,
    error_count INT,
    previous_error_count INT, -- for transposition 
    NODE_CHARACTER VARCHAR(1)
);

TYPE se_node_search_list IS TABLE OF node_search ;
```

However at the compilation I get : `PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements`.

I've been thinking of using a cursor, but looping on each line implies making a select to get the nodes accessible from the current node for each line. Plus, I'm not sure if I can populate another cursor to return for the current iteration in this way.

I tried declaring the record type in the current package and the table type as a global type, but then it cannot access the current type.

This function is executed to help with autocomplete at run time, so I have a strong execution-time constraint. The number of node however should not be higher than 5000.

What collection type can I return to get it to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define a schema level type and not plsql type. This error depicts that you are trying to access plsql type rather than SQL object. Hope tho helps.

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE node_search IS OBJECT (
    ID NUMBER,
    error_count NUMBER,
    previous_error_count NUMBER, -- for transposition 
    NODE_CHARACTER VARCHAR2(1)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE se_node_search_list IS TABLE OF node_search ;

Comment: Thank, but I tried that too, and record is not accepted in schema level type ><

So I tried to declare the record inside my package header, and access it through : 
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE se_node_search_list AS TABLE OF package_name.se_node_search;
 but i get : `PLS-00201: identifier 'SE_SEARCH.SE_NODE_SEARCH' must be declared`

Comment: It should not be package name. It should be the schema name where you are creating the type and also try creating OBJECT type rather than RECORD type

Comment: I cannot declare the record type directly in the schema, I get : `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RECORD" when expecting one of the following:

   array VARRAY_ table object fixed varying opaque sparse`

Comment: I have modified the answer with OBJECT type. Can u plz check that.

Comment: That does work, however does a table of object behave in the same way as a table of record ?

Comment: Yupps behavior is same but has some advantages over RECORD type like schema level definition etc. If this helped you can u plz accept the answer so it can be helpful to others

Comment: I had a mistake in my function that led me to think that object could not be used in place of record there. But in the end, that works. Thanks !